# How to take multiple actions without knowing which one is dispatched first?

Tags: redux-saga

How do I wait for both ACTION_A and ACTION_B to be dispatched without knowing which one was dispatched first?

I tried `const result = yield take([ACTION_A, ACTION_B])` but `result` is only the first dispatched action, whereas I need both actions.

I tried `const {a, b} = yield race({a: yield take(ACTION_A), b: yield take(ACTION_B)})` but if `a` is defined, `b` is not.

Remember I can't simply `yield take(ACTION_A); yield take(ACTION_B)` because I don't know which one comes first.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the `all` helper. `all` creates an Effect description that instructs the middleware to run multiple Effects in parallel and wait for all of them to complete.

Your code could look like this:

```
function* mySaga() {
  const [actionA, actionB] = yield all([
    take(ACTION_A),
    take(ACTION_B),
  ])
}
```

I hope my answer was helpful.